# Сделать неактивными забронированные дни

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

Делает неактивными только даты из последнего диапазона первый не учитывает. Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rentruss");
    $dates=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from reserve 
    where id_room='615'");
    
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($dates)) 
    {
        $date_start= $row['datearrive'];
        $date_end= $row['dateleave'];   
    
        $start = strtotime($date_start);
        $finish = strtotime($date_end);
     
        $array = array();
        for($i = $start; $i <= $finish; $i += 86400) {
            $list = explode('.', date('d.m.Y', $i));
            $array[] = implode('.', $list);
        } 
    }

    ?>
<script>
var array =JSON.parse('<?=json_encode($array) ?>');
$('input').datepicker({

    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
    
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Вы в каждой итерации цикла обнуляете `$array`. Поместите `$array = array();` перед началом цикла

Comment: `JSON.parse` уберите